# Cannot Read Property of Null when using Jquery inside Reactjs constructor to Extract JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS to make a web app that requires Jquery to extract remote JSON data from a server. The web app works when I works manually put in the JSON data into App.js but gives an error Cannot Read Property "polls" of Null when I try extracting remote JSON data.

Here is app.js with the JSON data manually put in:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Polls from './Components/Polls';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
      this.state = {
          polls:  [
          {
              survey_id: 1,
              choice1_votes: 4,
              choice1_text: "Kanye",
              choice1_image:"https://a.web.site/kanye.jpg",
              choice2_votes: 5,
              choice2_text:"Eminem",
              choice2_image:"https://a.web.site/eminem.jpg"
          },
          {
              survey_id: 2,
              choice1_votes: 7,
              choice1_text: "Football",
              choice1_image:"https://a.web.site/football.jpg",
              choice2_votes: 2,
              choice2_text: "Soccer",
              choice2_image:"https://a.web.site/soccer.jpg"
          }
      ]
};
      console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        My App
        <Polls polls={this.state.polls}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I try changing this.state to get data extracted using Jquery...

```
constructor(){
    super();
    $.getJSON('sample.json', function (data) {
      this.state = {data};
    });
  }
```

... I get an error Cannot read property 'polls' of null.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

The way you structured the code is not correct, write it like this:

First define the polls variable in `state` (initial value):

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        polls: []
    }
}
```

Load the JSON in [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method, and use `setState` to update the `state` value:

```
componentDidMount(){
    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: (data) => {
          this.setState({data: polls});
       },
       error: (xhr, status, err) => {
          console.error('error');
       }
   });
}
```

**Note**: Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to bind the proper context.

**Update:**

The way you wrote will work only when you load the local json, you need to use [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or jquery ajax call to make a get call to get that json from remote server.

Comment: It doesn't appear that componentDidMount() ever runs. I'm left with an object: {polls : [null]}. Am I supposed to call it somewhere?

Comment: no you don't need to call, do `console.log('called')` inside that it will get called surely once component will get rendered first time.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I'm still trying to get it to work.

Comment: just replace the url in componentDidMount method with the url of json that you are fetching it will work, i didn't say you downvoted :)

Comment: Can the URL be sample.json if I want to test a local JSON file first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145579/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-ethernetz).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be an async issue. `$.getJSON()` I believe is an async function and as such, it does not stop execution. When you get to the line in the constructor where this is called, the program starts executing `$.getJSON()` but since that function has idle time, the execution of `constructor()` continues. Meaning that `constructor()` finished execution probably before `$.getJSON()`, and therefore the `render()` function attempts to get starts execution  and attempts to reference `this.state.polls` before you have set the value for it.

If you follow Mayank Shukla's answer, you should be able to avoid this problem since in the constructor you *do* define `this.state.polls` as an empty array (which is not null or undefined)